# TensorFlow equivalent of numpy.all()

Tags: tensorflow

As stated in the title, is there a TensorFlow equivalent of the numpy.all() function to check if all the values in a bool tensor are `True`? What is the best way to implement such a check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [tf.reduce_all](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction#reduce_all), as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant([True,False,True,True],dtype=tf.bool)
res=tf.reduce_all(a)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
res.eval()
```

This returns `False`.

On the other hand, this returns `True`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant([True,True,True,True],dtype=tf.bool)
res=tf.reduce_all(a)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
res.eval()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tf.experimental.numpy.all` in tf 2.4

```
x = tf.constant([False, False])
tf.experimental.numpy.all(x)
```

Comment: In the end, the implementation of `tf.experimental.numpy.all` uses `tf.math.reduce_all` [Link to code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/13850c96e4c47c29bd7d822ce4d19c97d7e404a0/tensorflow/python/ops/numpy_ops/np_array_ops.py#L420)

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this problem would be to do:

```
def all(bool_tensor):
    bool_tensor = tf.cast(bool_tensor, tf.float32)
    all_true = tf.equal(tf.reduce_mean(bool_tensor), 1.0)
    return all_true
```

However, it's not a TensorFlow dedicated funciton. Just a workaround.